# How to set an ID on a div with the class "contentclass" in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to do some stuff with javascript on a div with the class "contentclass" in wordpress.

i need to use the document.getElementById to get the div (i cant use getElementByClassName for other reasons).

As such, i need to set an ID for that div, but i cant for the life of me figure out what file the div is generated from.

If someone could please let me know which file contains the relevant code, i would be hugely grateful.

Here is a screen of the div i am talking about (the one selected in blue):

[image]

Thanks

Cheers
Corey

PS:
I am using a modified version of the virtue theme at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just downloaded the Virtue theme and the file you are looking for is in the theme's root directory and is called `base.php`.

it contains the line you require: `<div class="wrap contentclass" role="document">`

Add the ID you require and you shouldn't need any JS...

NOTE: Any "customisation" should be done using a Child Theme! - You should do this which would mean you duplicate the `base.php`, make your customisations and then any future upgrades to your theme will keep your changes.

Answer (score 0):

That code is likely generated from one of the theme files. Hard to say exactly which one from the information offered.

Any good reason why you can't lookup by class name? This code would likely provide you with the element you're looking for:

```
var contentclass = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByClassName('contentclass')[0];
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using JS to achieve this - what would happen to your page is JS was disabled? As fstanis has said, you should find the wrapper in your theme files.